# Python MySQLdb Object Oriented

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, mysql-python

I am trying to establish connection with MySQL database using Python
on RaspberryPi. I am new to object oriented python. In this code I am
taking a value as input and trying to insert it in the database. Due
to some issue, The insert query is not getting executed and the
`Exception` part is getting executed. Please help me in identifying my
mistake.

```
import tkinter as tk
import MySQLdb   

class ImgComp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)        
        container = tk.Frame(self,width=320, height=209)        
        container.pack(side="top")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_propagate(False)

        try:
            self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","sample")
            self.c= self.db.cursor()                
        except:
            print ("I can't connect to MySql")
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (InputPage):            
            frame = F(container, self)                
            self.frames[F] = frame            
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(InputPage)   

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]                    
        if ((cont == PageOne) | (cont == InputPage) | (cont == OutputPage)):            
            self['menu'] = frame.menubar                
        else: 
            self['menu'] = ''            
        frame.tkraise()

    def input_submit(self, input_value):            

        in_val = float(input_value)
        self.sql = "INSERT INTO input_delay_master (input_delay) VALUES (%s)"                
        try:                   
            c.execute(self.sql,(in_val))                    
            self.db.commit()
        except:                    
            print("Except")
            self.db.rollback()         

class InputPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)            
        filemenu.add_command(label="Output Reset Delay", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(OutputPage))                        
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=filemenu)        
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Input Image Delay")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)                       
        input_delay = tk.Entry(self)
        input_delay.pack(pady=10)
        submit1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit", command=lambda: controller.input_submit(input_delay.get()))
        submit1.pack()
```

I get the following output

```
34.56 # This is the the value I entered in Entry field    

Except
```

The problem is, the insert query present inside the `input_submit` button is not getting executed, rather `Expection` part is executed. Please help me getting the way out to successfully execute the insert query.

Comment: Try print inside try to debug

Comment: I tried it, it is not getting executed, directly except part is getting executed

Comment: for testing code remove `try/except` and you will see error message with useful information (instead of useless `"Except"`). Or at least use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`.

Comment: I'm not sure but probably `execute` expect `?` instead of `(%s)` in query.

Comment: @furas I got the message in ex as "not all arguments converted during string formatting". I tried replacing %s with ? it did not worked

Comment: so now you have useful information. As I said I'm not sure but `execute` may use  `?` instead of `(%s)` to put arguments. So now it can't find `?` in query and it doesn't know what to do with `in_val` - and you get `"not all arguments converted during string formatting"`

Comment: @furas '?' did not worked. Any other solution?

Comment: except may expect tuple or list with arguments (even if you have only one argument) - but `(in_val)` is not tuple, it is single element, To create tuple you need comma inside `(in_val, )`

Comment: BTW: your problem has nothing to do with tkinter - you could create example only with `mysql` and test your query.

Comment: @furas. Thank you, adding comma resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`except` expects `tuple` with arguments - even if you have only one argument - but `(in_val)` is not tuple, it is single element. To create `tuple` you need comma inside `(in_val, )`